# What does for(;i<=m;i++) mean?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I'm studying for my exam and I bumped into this example that has a line that says:

```
for(;i<=m;i++)
```

The thing I don't understand is why is there a `;` with nothing in front of it?
what does it do? What does it mean?

Comment: It means that the first part of the `for` statement was already set somewhere in the code. It would make more sense in a context - ie proper code provided.

Comment: You need basics to understand, see the for loop syntax: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for

Comment: That's the thing - it doesn't do anything.  The semi-colon is there to tell the compiler that what's coming next is the test to exit the loop (or not).  Presumably, `i` was setup beforehand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `for` statement has the following syntax:

```
for (declaration; condition; post-condition)
```

The declaration happens once and once only. The condition is checked at the start of each loop and determines whether the loop will proceed, and the post-condition happens at the end of the loop.

Any and all of these statements can be omitted.

Yours is simply a `for` loop that does not require a declaration, perhaps because something is already declared, like so:

```
int i = 0;
for (;i<=m;++i)
```

If you wanted a loop to run indefinitely, you could omit the second statement:

```
for (int i = 0; ;++i)
```

In this regard, infinite loops are typically written as

```
for (;;)
```

You may wish to omit the post-condition, perhaps because you're using iterators and change it during the loop

```
for (auto it = std::begin(v); it != std::end(v);)
```

Answer (score 4):

> what does it do, what does it mean ?

It means that the initializing part of the for-loop is empty, i.e. no loop-variable is initialized in the scope of the loop.
This construct is most common in situations where you want to access the loop variable after the loop is left, e.g. in

```
int i = 7;
for(; i < 100; ++i) {
    if(isPrime(i)) break;
}
assert(i == 11); // can access i now
```

Answer (score 2):

This means a part of this statement is declared somewhere before.

```
i=0

for(;i<=m;i++)
```

This loop says,for every time that i is smaller than m, I'm going to do whatever is in the code block. Whenever i reaches m value, I'll stop. After each iteration of the loop, it increments i by 1 (i++), so that the loop will eventually stop when it meets the i <=m.

Answer (score 1):

> The thing that i don't understand is why is there a ";" with nothing in front of it. what does it do, what does it mean.

It is a valid statement that does nothing.

You can have empty statements any where you like. It's quite common to see them in looping constructs.

Comment: so why is it there if it does nothing ?

Comment: @BonQuiQui `for` has to have 3 parts, separated by 2 semicolons. All 3 parts are optional, but semicolons must remain there.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier if it just wasn't there ?

Comment: @BonQuiQui Then how would you determine which of 3 parts was omitted?

Comment: yeah, i got it now, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The i variable must have been initialized somewhere else.. so it picks the value from there and the loop iterates from that value of i.

Comment: Note that you can put anything you want in that space, including stuff that has absolutely nothing to do with the for loop's operation.